# MoveIt multiple planning pipelines

Tags: ros, moveit, ompl, move-group-interface

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently found the pilz_industrial_motion_planner, It can plan industrial tipical movements (PTP, LIN and CIRC). Following the MoveIt tutorials [pilz_industrial_motion_planner tutorial](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/pilz_industrial_motion_planner/pilz_industrial_motion_planner.html) and the [prbt_moveit_config](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_resources/blob/master/prbt_moveit_config/launch/move_group.launch)  I've managed to work with ompl and pilz_industrial_motion_planner in RVIZ.

As the tutorial explains, using the pilz_industrial_motion_planner with the Python/C++ MoveIt interface is as simple as setting the planner_id to "PTP", "LIN" or "CIRC". The main issue is when you try to work with ompl and pilz_industrial_motion_planner in the same script.

Apparently you can only work with one planning pipeline at a time. When I try to work with the pilz_industrial_motion_planner having set ompl to default I get the following warning:
Cannot find planning configuration for group 'robot_1' using planner 'PTP'. Will use defaults instead.

When I set pilz_industrial_motion_planner to default I get the same error the other way (I can only plan with "PTP", "LIN" or "CIRC").

¿I'm mising something or is there a way or a workaround to work with both planning pipelines with the Python/C++ MoveIt interface?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/377005/moveit-multiple-planning-pipelines/) by [IgnacioUD](https://answers.ros.org/users/72126/ignacioud/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2021-04-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xxiaoxiong](https://answers.ros.org/users/106544/xxiaoxiong/) on 2022-05-31**:
hi, do you know how to set the pilz as the default planner when there're multiple pipelines, cause in my case, the default planner is always ompl even if i changed the default planner as pilz in the move_group launch file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. You need to be on Noetic or later, or build MoveIt from source to use multiple planning pipelines in Melodic or earlier. You already did this (since it works in Rviz), I just want to state it for the record.
2. You need to use not only `setPlannerId` (`LIN`, `PTP`, `CIRC`) but also `setPlanningPipelineId` (`pilz_industrial_motion_planner`).

If you find that a part of the tutorial is insufficient or an error message is not clear enough, please feel free to submit a pull request to improve it.

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2021-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [IgnacioUD](https://answers.ros.org/users/72126/ignacioud/) on 2021-04-26**:
Hi [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/), as always thank you for your accurate and quick response. I will indeed submit a pull request, a simple example script can be selfexplanatory for such things.
¿Is there a way of changing the planning pipeline using the Python interface?

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-04-26**:
Yes, soon. In the meantime you can use [these changes](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/pull/2622).